# Watir scroll down the page as long as there is more content to show

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I want to scroll down the page as long as there is more content to show.

For example, when you click followers on Instagram, a dialog window will pop up and it will load more followers as you scroll down as long as there are more followers to show.

[image: Instagram followers dialog window]

I could do this the hard way like getting the follower count and then counting the followers as I scroll down and when they equal stop scrolling there.

But I wanted to ask you whether there could be a better way.

Comment: Can you please include your code as well?

Comment: I didn't code the whole thing yet. I mean it would just be `browser.send_keys :page_down` if I wanted to scroll down the page (after focusing of course).
What I want to do is to scroll down as long as there is more content so you could never know how many times you would scroll down unless there is a way to figure it out and a way for that is the way I mentioned above.

Comment: Okay that's clear

Comment: Okay, actually i could not scroll that pop-up window using watir-scroll gem, wait until other people arrive here, they may be having some idea.

Comment: Thank you even for trying. :)

Comment: Another way I figured is to approximate how many times you would need to scroll down the page to the bottom using `browser.send_keys :control, :end` . That follower dialog window loads approximately 10 followers each time. So an approximation would be 

`scrolls_needed = (follower_count / 10.0).ceil`

Comment: Sorry, not an Instagram user. Is there a easier way to reproduce the issue without finding a lot of followers? If I create an account, I assume I wouldn't have enough followers to see the scrolling.

Comment: You could create an account and then just go to someone else's profile (a public account like a celebrity's etc.) . Then click on their follower count, this will open up the same follower dialog window which works the same way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a scrollable element is at the bottom by comparing its scrollTop and scrollHeight.

The following work:

```
scrollable = browser.div(class: 'j6cq2') # div with overflow-y=scroll
until browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].clientHeight >= arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable) do
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable)
    sleep(1)
end
```

Note that I didn't have time to find a better solution than using #sleep. However, hopefully this gives you an idea.

Comment: Works like a charm, but this two lines are necessary 
`browser.element(css: "li.Y8-fY a").click

sleep 3` because your program quickly executes even before the pop up appears.

Comment: Just what I wanted! Thank you so much! :) @Rajagopalan, but just to target the followers button you would need more than the class because both "followers" and "following" buttons have the same property if I am not mistaken. How I differentiate them is `browser.a(href: "/#{username}/followers/").click`

Comment: @AndréYuhai The Css selector I formed matches with two elements but the first one is followers so it receives the click.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know about it. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, sorry, I wrote this assuming that all the navigation and opening of the dialog already occurred. Ultimately, this should work for any scrollable element, not just the one on this Instagram page.

Comment: @Justin Ko your solution is amazing and awesome, no other could have written such an awesome coding. I have been waiting for your solution since I interacted with him because I know you would come up with such an awesome idea.